# Total data and add to index of array

Tags: php

I currently have an array called `contestData` that looks like this:

```
"BUNDLE" => array: [
    "audio"=> array:[
        "downloaded"=> [
            "this_week"=> "365"
            "today" => 987
        ]
        "saved"=> [
            "this_week"=> "56"
            "today" => 193
        ]
    ]
    "video"=> array:[
        "downloaded"=> [
            "this_week"=> "365"
            "today" => 987
        ]
        "saved"=> [
            "this_week"=> "56"
            "today" => 193
        ]
    ]
]
```

That shows this structure:

```
['BUNDLE']['audio']['downloaded']['this_week']
['BUNDLE']['video']['downloaded']['today']
['BUNDLE']['audio']['saved']['this_week']
['BUNDLE']['video']['saved']['today']
```

But now I'm trying to figure out how to, within a loop on this array, add the totals into a totals index called `contestTotals` like this:

```
//total for bundles saved this week and today
['BUNDLE']['contestTotals']['saved']['this_week']
['BUNDLE']['contestTotals']['saved']['today']


//total for bundled downloaded this week and today
['BUNDLE']['contestTotals']['downloaded']['this_week']
['BUNDLE']['contestTotals']['downloaded']['today']
```

So at that point I'm not worried about the audio or video type but simply totaling for the bundle type

Here is the loop, but I'm unsure of how to properly add and save the totals in this way

```
foreach ($this->contestData as $type => &$typeData) {
    if ($type !== 'contestTotals') {
        foreach ($typeData as $bundleType => &$bundleTypeData) {
            if(!isset($bundleTypeData['saved'])) $bundleTypeData['saved'] = [];
            foreach ($this->interval as $intervals){
                if(!isset($bundleTypeData['saved'][$intervals]))
                    $bundleTypeData['saved'][$intervals] = 0;
            }
            foreach ($this->interval as $intervals){
                if(!isset($prdCatData['downloaded'][$intervals]))
                    $prdCatData['downloaded'][$intervals] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are always getting this array in the same format?

Comment: @angel_deykov yes that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an example based on the initial bundle array you've shown:

```php
$bundle = [
    "audio" => [
        "downloaded"=> [
            "this_week"=> "365",
            "today" => 987,
        ],
        "saved"=> [
            "this_week"=> "56",
            "today" => 193,
        ],
    ],
    "video"=> [
        "downloaded"=> [
            "this_week"=> "365",
            "today" => 987,
        ],
        "saved"=> [
            "this_week"=> "56",
            "today" => 193,
        ],
    ],
];

foreach ($bundle as $category => $types) {
    foreach ($types as $type => $intervals) {
        foreach ($intervals as $interval => $value) {
            // add a contest total for the type and interval if it doesn't exist
            if (!isset($bundle['contestTotals'][$type][$interval])) {
                $bundle['contestTotals'][$type][$interval] = 0;
            }
            // add current value
            $bundle['contestTotals'][$type][$interval] += $value;
        }
    }
}
```

This would produce:

```
Array (
    [audio] => Array (
        [downloaded] => Array (
            [this_week] => 365
            [today] => 987
        )
        [saved] => Array (
            [this_week] => 56
            [today] => 193
        )
        )
    [video] => Array (
        [downloaded] => Array (
            [this_week] => 365
            [today] => 987
        )
        [saved] => Array (
            [this_week] => 56
            [today] => 193
        )
    )
    [contestTotals] => Array (
        [downloaded] => Array (
            [this_week] => 730
            [today] => 1974
        )
        [saved] => Array (
            [this_week] => 112
            [today] => 386
        )
    )
)
```

Basically, all you have to do is skip the "category" (audio, video...) in your totals.